# Was the Chai Sutta Chronicles season 2 retcon pre-planned or is it based on response to the prequel?

Tags: production, tvfs-chai-sutta-chronicles

I recently watched *TVF's Chai Sutta Chronicles* S02E01, and they just retcon everything established in *Chai Sutta Chronicles 2.0 Prequel - The Pursuit of Sadness*.

Now the prequel episode just made into a dream, was that pre-planned from start? Or was it changed after the response to *Prequel - The Pursuit of Sadness*?